PC getting stuck after fresh install on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Hardware Lenovo laptop 1235U, Hp 445 G7 ryzen 4500U, Custom PC b450 ryzen 3600
PC getting stuck after fresh install on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Hardware Lenovo laptop 1235U, Hp 445 G7 ryzen 4500U, Custom PC b450 ryzen 3600
I am a developer and I have been using these devices for more then a year but on windows they never got stuck,
Lenovo Laptop is 12th Gen i5, 1235U CPU and 8GB RAM and 256GB SSD
Hp Probook 445 G7 with Ryzen 5 4500U with 32GB RAM and 1TB SSD
Custom PC with Ryzen 5 3600 with B450 Motherboard and Nvidia GTX 750 TI with 32GB RAM
All have same instability issues, Lenovo laptop gets stuck when I try to run the VS Code.
HP laptop and Custom PC gets stuck everytime I try to run the Jetbrains Products Like Webstorm, PhpStorm , or Goland etc,
is there something wrong with latest release or with the Kernel or I need to switch the kernel or anything else.
Can somebody guide me with this?
I also have another PC with core i5-10400 with 32GB RAM and GT 730 and it works fine with 24.04 LTS
